# How to generate JWT in python according to the requirement

Tags: python, jwt

I'm trying to generate JWT to use it in a API integration. [Here](https://developers.miro.com/docs/boards-picker#section-generate-jwt-on-your-backend) are the specific requirements to generate JWT token but I'm not following how to do it in python.

It shows following Java snippet:

```
JWT.create()  
   .withIssuer("CLIENT_ID")
   .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)))
   .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256("CLIENT_SECRET"));
```

And accordingly, I'm trying to create it...
Here I'm using [JWT](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/) lib in python and here is my code:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone    
from jwt import JWT
from jwt.utils import get_int_from_datetime
    
instance = JWT()
    
message = {
   'iss': 'CLIENT_ID',
   'exp': get_int_from_datetime(datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(hours=23))
}
    
signing_key = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
    
compact_jws = instance.encode(message, signing_key, alg='HS256')
print('compact_jws', compact_jws)
```

But the above code gives me the following error:

> TypeError: key must be an instance of a class implements jwt.AbstractJWKBase

I'm not sure whether the code I've written is correct according to the requirements or not, please help me.

Comment: Your `signing_key` is just a plain `string`.  And it should be instance [of subtype] of `jwt.AbstractJWKBase`

Comment: Yeah, I understood it from the error message, but how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 12):

Try to use **pyjwt**:
[PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
instead of **jwt**

Then you can do the following:

```
encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

install it with:

```
pip install pyjwt
```

and use it as:

```
import jwt
```